# How to search the database for a field which is a substring of the query by using sqlite

Tags: sqlite

## Problem description

I want to search for the **query = Angela** in a database from a table called Variations. The problem is that the database does not **Angela**. It contains **Angel**. As you can see the **a** is missing.

---

## Searching procedure

The table that I want to query is the following:

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS VARIATIONS 
    (ID        INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
     ID_ENTITE INTEGER, 
     NAME      TEXT, 
     TYPE      TEXT, 
     LANGUAGE  TEXT);"
```

To search for the query I am using `fts4` because it is faster than `LIKE%` especially if I have a big database with more than 10 millions rows. I cannot also use the **equality** since i am looking for substrings.

1. I create a virtual table `create virtual table variation_virtual using fts4(ID, ID_ENTITE, NAME, TYPE, LANGUAGE);`
2. Filled the virtual table with VARIATIONS `insert into variation_virtual select * from VARIATIONS;`
3. The selection query is represented as follow:

   ```
   SELECT ID_ENTITE, NAME FROM variation_virtual WHERE NAME MATCH "Angela";
   ```

---

## Question

What am I missing in the query. What I am doing is the opposite of when we want to check if a query is a subtring of a string in a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use fts4 for this. From the [documentation](http://sqlite.org/fts3.html):

```
SELECT count(*) FROM enrondata1 WHERE content MATCH 'linux';  /* 0.03 seconds */
SELECT count(*) FROM enrondata2 WHERE content LIKE '%linux%'; /* 22.5 seconds */
```

> Of course, the two queries above are not
>   entirely equivalent. For example the LIKE query matches rows that
>   contain terms such as "linuxophobe" or "EnterpriseLinux" (as it
>   happens, the Enron E-Mail Dataset does not actually contain any such
>   terms), whereas the MATCH query on the FTS3 table selects only those
>   rows that contain "linux" as a discrete token. Both searches are
>   case-insensitive.

So your query will only match strings that have 'Angela' as a word (at least that is how I interpret 'discrete token').

Comment: Should I add an extra layer to compute string similarity? line for example the levenshtein distance

Comment: Well that leads you into the field of 'fuzzy searching', which is really complicated to do right. I know a certain search engine company that knows all about that...